# IOS:Access Storyboard from NSObject

Tags: ios, storyboard

In an effort to practice MVC (and also loosely following a tutorial) I have placed a method that imports address book contacts in a separate data class known as `Model.h` that inherits from `NSObject`.  It is not a `UIViewController` but rather an `NSObject`.

The problem I've run into is that if access to contacts has been denied, I would like to jump to another view controller.  And `NSObject` apparently does not give you access to the `storyboard`.

Communication between the Model and the View controller that handles what happens is currently through `NSNotificationCenter` but I can't figure out how to communicate the fact concisely that user has denied access to contacts.

Can anyone suggest way to allow access to storyboard from an `NSObject` or alternatively, communicate from the `NSObject` to the active `UIViewController` that this access has been denied.

```
- (void)fetchAddressBookContacts
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    switch (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()) {

        case kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
        {
            NSLog(@"User has already granted access to the Address Book");
             [self extractContactsFromAddressBookAlt];
            break;
        }
        case kABAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        {
            NSLog(@"User has denied access to the Address Book");

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [self gotoNewVC];//does not work
            });
            break;
        }
    }
    if (addressBook) {
        CFRelease(addressBook);}
} 
//following is not getting called from NSObject
-(void) gotoNewVC {
             UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newVC"];

        UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
SlowViewController*view=[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

make right instance of view controller, Thanks